# Como converter chaves do array para tudo maiúsculo ou minúsculo?

Tags: php, array

Estou recebendo uns dados de um `Webservice`, através de uma resposta em JSON.

Converto esses dados de JSON para `array`, através de `json_decode`. Porém uma coisa que está me incomodando é o fato das chaves estão vindo com o nome em CamelCase.

Algo parecido com isso:

```
['Id' => 44, 'NumeroDoCliente' => 55, 'ProdutoCodigoNum' => 77]
```

A minha preocupação é que eu já tive problema com o "excesso de capricho"  (ou desorganização, como queiram) em webservices onde os dados vinha em CamelCase. Um exemplo, o id vinha como `Id`, e depois "refatoraram" para `ID`, o que causou um grande problema para mim, e parou meu sistema.

Então eu queria criar uma normalização desses índices, transformando eles para upper case ou lower case.

Existe alguma maneira de trocar o "caso" dos índices em PHP? Existe alguma maneira de converter todas as chaves para upper case ou lower case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe sim, a função [array_change_key_case](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_change_key_case.asp), Wallace. Veja:

```
$arr = ['Id' => 44, 'NumeroDoCliente' => 55, 'ProdutoCodigoNum' => 77];
```

Para *upper case*:

```
$upperKeys = array_change_key_case($arr, CASE_UPPER);
print_r($upperKeys); // Array ( [ID] => 44 [NUMERODOCLIENTE] => 55 [PRODUTOCODIGONUM] => 77 )
```

Para *lower case*:

```
$lowerKeys = array_change_key_case($arr, CASE_LOWER);
print_r($lowerKeys); // Array ( [id] => 44 [numerodocliente] => 55 [produtocodigonum] => 77 )
```

Comment: Boa. Isso já salva parte do meu trabalho +1

Comment: O que falta? @WallaceMaxters

Comment: Terminar de tratar os dados do webservice, kkkkkk. O resto deixa comigo aqui, valeu :D